# Gradient BG in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, gradient

I created a `UICollectionView` with cell like a credit cards and want to add gradient layer as a background of this cards. First I added background view for shadow(`shadowView`) and then add second view for gradient layer(`bgView`) and add `CAGradientLayer` as subLayer of `bgView`. But I didn't get any **gradient** view. This is my code:

```
class CardCell: BaseCell {

    private var shadowView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.shadowColor.cgColor
        view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.0)
        view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
        view.layer.shadowRadius = 15.0
        return view
    }()

    private var bgView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.layer.addSublayer(createGradientLayer(for: view))
        return view
    }()

    override func setup() {
        super.setup()
        addSubview(shadowView)
        addSubview(bgView)

        // setup constraints
        shadowView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.9).isActive = true
        shadowView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        shadowView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        shadowView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        bgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: shadowView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        bgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: shadowView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        bgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: shadowView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        bgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: shadowView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

    }

    private static func createGradientLayer(for view: UIView) -> CAGradientLayer {
        let color = UIColor(red:0.95, green:0.42, blue:0.64, alpha:1.0)
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [color.cgColor, color.withAlphaComponent(0.7).cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.1, y: 1.1)
        return gradientLayer
    }

}
```

But If I change this code and remove gradient setting from `bgView init` and write it after constraints, everything is OK, BUT the **shadow view** go away:

```
. . .
bgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: shadowView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
bgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: shadowView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

bgView.layoutIfNeeded()
bgView.layer.addSublayer(CardCell.createGradientLayer(for: bgView))
```

[image]

Comment: Is [this](https://ibb.co/jvC08o) similar to what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Try Add views to cell's contentview `contentView.addSubview(shadowView)`
        `contentView.addSubview(bgView)`

Comment: @LalKrishna nothing changed :(

Comment: can you add a screenshot of what you trying to achieve?

Comment: @LalKrishna added screenshot. I want to add shadow to that cards on image.

Comment: Please check my updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51606618/4061501). @JackDaniel

Answer (score 1):

```
extension UIView {
func addGradientToViewWithCornerRadiusAndShadow(radius:CGFloat,firstColor:UIColor,secondColor:UIColor,locations:[CGFloat]){
        for layer in (self.layer.sublayers ?? []){
            if let layer1 = layer as? CAGradientLayer{
                layer1.removeFromSuperlayer()
            }
        }
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        var rect = self.bounds
        rect.size.width = ScreenWidth
        gradient.frame = rect
        gradient.colors = [firstColor.cgColor, secondColor.cgColor]
        gradient.locations = locations as [NSNumber]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 1)
        gradient.cornerRadius = radius
        gradient.shadowRadius = 2
        gradient.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        gradient.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: 0.5, height: 0.5)
        gradient.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
}
```

try using this UIView's extension.Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think your gradient layer add on your shadow view show your shadow view disappear..You should always add gradient layer at 0 index of layers.

```
bgView.layer.insertSublayer(CardCell.createGradientLayer(for: bgView), at: 0)
```

and Your layer creation method you need to use frame instead bounds.

```
private static func createGradientLayer(for view: UIView) -> CAGradientLayer {
    let color = UIColor(red:0.95, green:0.42, blue:0.64, alpha:1.0)
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = view.frame
    gradientLayer.colors = [color.cgColor, color.withAlphaComponent(0.7).cgColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = nil
    return gradientLayer
}
```

Comment: the problem stays the same. It didn't help :(

Comment: Please check updated answer...use frame instead bounds.

Comment: try to set locations to nil as updated answer and remove start and ent point. and use two different color.

Comment: didn't changed anything

Answer (score 0):

The problem is When you add the gradient view the `bgView` is not layout completely. So the bound will be zero.

**Solution:**

```
private var gradient: CAGradientLayer?

override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.setup()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        shadowView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: shadowView.bounds).cgPath

        if let gradient = gradient {
            gradient.frame = bgView.bounds
        } else {
            gradient = TestCell.createGradientLayer(for: bgView)
            bgView.layer.addSublayer(gradient!)
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]